# Typewriter effect in console with NodeJS/Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, code-snippets

I've been busy for some days now with a small text-based RPG within a console with NodeJS and Typescript.

Now I'm busy with the dialogs and everything story based and I was wondering
if there is a snippet or lib out there that can help me create a typewriter effect in a console.
I've been searching on Google and Stack Overflow, but so far everything I found is HTML/CSS + JS.
And that is not really what I'm looking for

So if anyone is able to help me out with this, that would be amazing!

Thanks in advance
Kawaaii

Comment: Maybe a library like `terminal-kit` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-kit) could help you?

Comment: Wow, never seen that package yet! This could be very helpful!

Comment: As far as I've seen that package doesn't have a typewriter effect, but it's an amazing package beside that!

Comment: I have to apologize for my previous answer, I have looked better at it and it has a typewriter effect!